# GWT Windows gadget displayed incorrectly

Tags: java, gwt, windows-desktop-gadgets

I created a Windows gadget (Windows sidebar gadget) using GWT but it is displayed incorrectly. In IE it looks good, but gadget is shown as a small white box.

Answer (score 0):

You should use ie6 user agent and single script linker in your gwt.xml:

```
<set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6" />
<add-linker name="sso"/>
```